# Manually changing username in Asp.Net Membership

Tags: asp.net

I am able to change a username by directly accessing the asp.net membership user tables.  However, the old username is preserved in a new row and assigned a new UserID automatically by asp.net.  How do I stop that from happening?

**EDIT: only in the users table and roles table, not the membership table.**

```
var mUser = dc.aspnet_Users
            .Where(u => u.UserId == (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey)
            .Select(u => u).SingleOrDefault();

mUser.UserName = newName;
mUser.LoweredUserName = newName.ToLower();

try
{
    dc.SubmitChanges();
}
catch
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: i got it to work it seems the problem had to do with assigning a role to the old membership object for the users old name that didnt exist. so a new roles row was added automatically and a userid created by the roles classes.

Comment: So, what did you do to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 10):

Changing username is not supported by the sql membership provider in ASP.NET 2.0. You can still change the username but you have to use custom implementation.

Also you have to update the membership cookie with the new username in order to avoid recreation of the user with the same username but new UserId.

In the example below I use Linq to SQL to update the membership tables - I have data context called MembershipDataContext.

```
public bool ChangeUserName(Guid userId, string newUserName)
{
    bool success = false;
    newUserName = newUserName.Trim();

    // Make sure there is no user with the new username
    if (Membership.GetUser(newUserName) == null)
    {
        MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(userId);
        string oldUsername = u.UserName;
        // get current application

        MembershipDataContext context = new MembershipDataContext ();
        aspnet_User userToChange = (from user in context.aspnet_Users
                                    where user.UserId == userId
                                    select user).FirstOrDefault();

        if (userToChange != null)
        {
            userToChange.UserName = newUserName;
            userToChange.LoweredUserName = newUserName.ToLower();

            context.SubmitChanges();

            // ASP.NET Issues a cookie with the user name. 
            // When a request is made with the specified cookie, 
            // ASP.NET creates a row in aspnet_users table.
            // To prevent this sign out the user and then sign it in

            string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
            HttpCookie authCookie = 
              HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = null;

            try
            {
                authTicket = 
                    FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

                FormsIdentity formsIdentity = 
                    new FormsIdentity(
                        new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                            authTicket.Version, 
                            newUserName, 
                            authTicket.IssueDate, 
                            authTicket.Expiration, 
                            authTicket.IsPersistent, 
                            authTicket.UserData));

                string y = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                string[] roles = 
                    authTicket.UserData.Split(new char[] { '|' });
                System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal genericPrincipal = 
                    new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(
                                                        formsIdentity, 
                                                        roles);

                HttpContext.Current.User = genericPrincipal;
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {
                // Handle exceptions
            }
            catch( NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                // Handle exceptions
            }

            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(newUserName, false);
            success = true;
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: when you use FormsAuthentication.setauthcookie, isnt the cookie created for you? why manually create as you did?

Comment: I don't set the cookie manually I just use it to get instance of the FormsAuthenticationTicket.

Comment: my point was that i dont understand why you need to get the instance of the ticket. If you just signout and sign back in isnt that enough?

Comment: I use it to update the current user identity - HttpContext.Current.User in the same request. If I do not do that it will return the old user-name.

Answer (score 1):

How did you change the username? I just did it by using an update sql statement and updated the username without creating new rows or preserving the old username.

```
UPDATE [MyDatabase].[dbo].[aspnet_Users] 
SET [UserName] = 'mynewusername',
    [LoweredUserName] = LOWER('mynewusername')
WHERE [UserName] = 'myusername'
```

Comment: please provide more details.. the problem might be in the linq query you used to do the update. the sql code above updates the username field without causing a new record to be created.

Comment: see above. i also ran it with sql statements and same result

Comment: I am not able to replicate this issue on my end. If at all possible, try running SQL Profiler to look at the actual SQL command generated by your application.

Comment: just curious are you using roles?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change both UserName and LoweredUserName...  I assume the API used the other field, did the lookup, observed the record didn't exist (because the one was changed), and created a new one.  Typically, it doesn't preserve the old records.

**EDIT:** Could the issue also be you are looking up the account by the ProviderUserKey field?

Comment: i had changed both. the new username works fine, but the table has the added row for old name. (only in the users table and roles table, not in the membership table)

Comment: Could the issue be the provideruserkey field that you are querying by?  Also, you use SingleOrDefault, why no null check?