# About MembershipDataContext namespace/reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am using the code at [MembershipDataContext](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2153340/635634)  to change username in aspnet_user table in my web form code behind.
But it is not working because MembershipDataContext namespace could not be found.
Google search but no result.

Thanks

UPDATE:

```
public bool ChangeUserName(Guid userId, string newUserName)
{
    bool success = false;
    newUserName = newUserName.Trim();

    // Make sure there is no user with the new username
    if (Membership.GetUser(newUserName) == null)
    {
        MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(userId);
        string oldUsername = u.UserName;
        // get current application

        MembershipDataContext context = new MembershipDataContext ();
        aspnet_User userToChange = (from user in context.aspnet_Users
                                    where user.UserId == userId
                                    select user).FirstOrDefault();

        if (userToChange != null)
        {
            userToChange.UserName = newUserName;
            userToChange.LoweredUserName = newUserName.ToLower();

            context.SubmitChanges();

            // ASP.NET Issues a cookie with the user name. 
            // When a request is made with the specified cookie, 
            // ASP.NET creates a row in aspnet_users table.
            // To prevent this sign out the user and then sign it in

            string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
            HttpCookie authCookie = 
              HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = null;

            try
            {
                authTicket = 
                    FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

                FormsIdentity formsIdentity = 
                    new FormsIdentity(
                        new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                            authTicket.Version, 
                            newUserName, 
                            authTicket.IssueDate, 
                            authTicket.Expiration, 
                            authTicket.IsPersistent, 
                            authTicket.UserData));

                string y = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                string[] roles = 
                    authTicket.UserData.Split(new char[] { '|' });
                System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal genericPrincipal = 
                    new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(
                                                        formsIdentity, 
                                                        roles);

                HttpContext.Current.User = genericPrincipal;
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {
                // Handle exceptions
            }
            catch( NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                // Handle exceptions
            }

            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(newUserName, false);
            success = true;
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: I use: using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Linq;

Comment: right-click on `MembershipDataContext` and arrow over "Resolve"

Comment: It doesn't show reslove, which means a wrong reference. I could not found it in MSDN at all.

Comment: how did it get there in the first place?

Comment: Where did this code come from?

Comment: @CharlieKilian - The code came directly from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2153340/635634).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code from the question you refer to defines a Linq to SQL entity data context named `MembershipDataContext` (which makes it a definition of [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx)). There isn't a built in type (that I'm aware of or could find) named `MembershipDataContext`.

[Here is another example](http://code.google.com/p/rapidwebdev/source/browse/trunk/src/RapidWebDev.Platform/?r=346#RapidWebDev.Platform/Linq) of a project which does the same thing (dbml definition included).

Answer (score 0):

Data context usually refers to linq. Are you using Linq? If so, `DataContext` is the [actual class](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDcQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx&ei=zJCNT8_-LZLdiAKA_4G7CA&usg=AFQjCNF1sVeeZFJ7IlaKQADa0G-0OE41AQ&sig2=6yN_ul49AvhbmFKZrGzFOg) as the `Member` part is your custom generated class from your DBML file.

I hope this helps.